# How to run main class in test folder?

Tags: scala, sbt

If I have a simple object with a `main` method in the `test` folder of a project, how do I run it with sbt?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
sbt "test:runMain path.to.MainObjectInTest"
```

Answer (score 7):

...And if you have multiple projects in you sbt file  then:

```
sbt "projectName/test:runMain path.to.MainObjectInTest"
```

or just use:

```
sbt "projectName/test:run"
```

If you have only one object with main, this will run it. If you have multiple objects with main, it will ask you to select which one to run.